# Any good tpk\tpkx file converters?

Tags: maps, gis, file-converter

I would like to know if good, paineless, tpk/tpkx to any other tile format exists.
For example, converting to shapefiles etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require a really a painless way, I would recommend using an ArGIS solution (though this one is not free).

As tpk is [defined](https://esri-es.github.io/awesome-arcgis/arcgis/content/data-storage/file-formats/tpk/) as a layer package, you have to:

1. [Extract that package](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/extract-package.htm) using a data management toolbox available in ArcMap software (you get a set of specific objects)
2. Use [available tools](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-conversion-toolbox.htm) to export specific layers one by one (mostly raster exports involved).

I have also seen similar attempt in [QGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70084660/reading-importing-tpk-maps-into-r-or-qgis-and-use-as-shapefile), though it looks like a bit more complicated.

HOWEVER this specific question should be rather put in a [GIS forum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=tpk), where you can already find some similar answers, like [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302676/extracting-data-from-vector-tile-package-vtpk-using-arcgis-pro) (which implies to use ArcGIS Pro). And maybe [this reply](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190966/export-arcgis-tiles-data-to-any-image-format) could bring you to the actual export capability.

**So in sum:** use an ArcGIS (as it is native for this application), if you want to know how to achieve in detail, turn to mentioned GIS forum.

Comment: Thank you.
I actually posted here after having posted in the GIS forum and being redirected here

Comment: Okay here to ask what tool to use, but if you will be after how to achieve it, turn back there :)